# Why a file starting with ~$ is created when opening a word document?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

We all might have noticed the creation of a file named `"~$filename.docx"`(hidden) when opening `filename.docx` using MS Word

**What is the purpose of this file?**

**Why is it created and what does it contain?**

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions; this is not a programming question, and would have been better suited over at [SU]

Comment: Depends on the context. I encountered a "~$filename.docx" file when my program was manipulating Word docx files. This is a valid programming question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It maintains temporary information about the current state of the document.

Have you ever encountered a crash and when you open Word it asks you to recover certain documents that were being edited? That's where it gets that information.

Comment: When i try to open the file separately, ms word was not able to open that file and it asked for repair. So is it just have the the change logs kind of information?

Comment: Yes @iamprem , '~$filename.docx' only contains change logs information