# git add permission denied windows10

Tags: git

When I run `git add .`

Then the following message:

> error: open("~$myfile.pptx"): Permission denied
>
> error: unable to index file ~$myfile.pptx
>
> fatal: adding files failed

So I　run `Icacls myfile.pptx  /grant user:(F,WD)`

But still error.

How to change the rigth permission?

Comment: `~$myfile.pptx` != `myfile.pptx`. One might be a temporary file with a lock? In other words, don't `git add .` but try adding only the specific file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~$myfile.pptx` is a separate file from your powerpoint file `myfile.pptx`. [Those are temporary files created by powerpoint while you have the original open.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950333/why-a-file-starting-with-is-created-when-opening-a-word-document)

[It is safe for git to ignore those files. Create a `.gitignore` file at the base of your project or add this line to it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308610/how-to-ignore-certain-files-in-git)

```
~$*
```

At which `git status` shouldn't show that file anymore and `git add .` won't try to commit it any longer.

[Also, here is a widely used .gitignore file for MS office files](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/MicrosoftOffice.gitignore)