# os.listdir() adds characters to the beginning of file name?

Tags: python, excel, filenames

I had a quick google of this but couldn't find anything. I'm using os to get a list of all the file names in the current working directory using the following code:

```
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
```

The list of files returns fine,  but the last element has an extra '~$' that isn't in the actual file name. For example:

```
files
['File1.xlsx', 'File2.xlsx', '~$File3.xlsx']
```

This is then causing an issue when I iterate through these files to try and import them, as I get the error of:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\$File3.xlsx'
```

If anyone knows why this happens and how I can fix/prevent it, that would be great!

Comment: Just realised it was because I had File3 open in Excel already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thought I'd answer in case anyone else has this issue.

It's nothing to do with os. It happened because I had File3 open in Excel while pulling the list of file names. I've found out that opening a microsoft document creates a temporary 'lock' file, which are denoted by '~$' (this is how it can re-open unsaved data if it crashes etc).

I found the below from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/is-in-front-of-my-file-name-open-it/54b19aed-4b16-4f96-a4bc-3a8c5476a164):

> The files you are describing are so-called owner files (sometimes
> referred to as "lock" files). An owner file is created when you work
> with a document ... and it should be deleted when you save your
> document and exit.

There's also a SO question about this within Microsoft files, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950333/why-a-file-starting-with-is-created-when-opening-a-word-document)